# Struts 2 app running after restarting tomcat

Tags: tomcat, struts2

I am trying to learn Struts 2 and Tomcat from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2

I created the project with NetBeans. When I deploy the war file on Tomcat there is the error HTTP Status 404 – Not Found, but after stopping and starting Tomcat the app works ok.

What is wrong?

This is in the logfile:

```
12, 2020 7:07:46 ΜΜ org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig
release SEVERE: Failed to destroy the filter named [struts2] of type
[org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org/apache/struts2/util/ObjectFactoryDestroyable    at
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.cleanup(Dispatcher.java:322) at
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.PrepareOperations.cleanupDispatcher(PrepareOperations.java:206) at
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.destroy(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:151) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.release(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:318) at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStop(StandardContext.java:5071) at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5924) at
org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:1136) at
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy(HostConfig.java:1597) at
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.checkResources(HostConfig.java:1524) at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1783) at
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:366) at
org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1505) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1676) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1686) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1654) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.apache.struts2.util.ObjectFactoryDestroyable    at
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1951) at
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1794) ... 18 more
```

Comment: If you solved it then answer your own question and mark it accepted.

Comment: It seems that the problem exists...

Comment: What version of everything are you using? How are you managing dependencies?